# Can Chrome extensions intercept WebSocket traffic?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

I would like to intercept all WebSocket traffic from a Chrome extension.  But I don't know if this can even be done.

Comment: AFAIK the only way is to hook WebSocket.prototype methods in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently.  I'm just hoping there's a nicer way.  Hooking the `WebSocket` constructor takes a lot of code to intercept sent and received messages.

Comment: Well, the only other method is chrome.webRequest but I don't think you'll be able to read the body/data. Ah, and of course there's always chrome.debugger with full access to [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/) but that's kinda nuclear.

Comment: In Puppeteer it's literally 3 lines: `const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await cdp.send('Network.enable');
  await cdp.send('Page.enable');
  cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', frame => { // do stuff });` Does this work in extensions too?

Comment: See my previous comment, it's what chrome.debugger is for.

Comment: I'll check it out.